# Declaring a cursor with "WITH HOLD" inside a function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ref-cursor

I'm using postgresql 10.3.
Following function returns a cursor bound to a query

```
CREATE FUNCTION reffunc1(text) RETURNS refcursor AS '
DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR SELECT col FROM test where col=$1;
BEGIN
    OPEN mycursor;
    RETURN mycursor;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

I needed to make the returned cursor "WITH HOLD". I did as follows.

```
CREATE FUNCTION reffunc2(text) RETURNS refcursor AS '
DECLARE mycursor CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT col FROM test where col=$1;
BEGIN
    OPEN mycursor;
    RETURN mycursor;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
```

Why cannot we use WITH HOLD inside the function here?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52991/110455

Comment: There is no `with hold` when declaring a cursor variable: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-DECLARATIONS

Comment: There is. Please refer https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-declare.html

Comment: That is the DECLARE statement in **SQL**. When declaring a cursor _variable_ in PL/pgSQL there is no such option. Don't confuse the `DECLARE` _section_ in **PL/pgSQL** with the declare _statement_ in SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then why does the following work?
"DECLARE mycursor CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT col FROM testtable;"
I can declare as above(outside a function) and fetch data.

Comment: Because that's a **SQL _statement_**, _not_ a PL/pgSQL **`declare` _section_**.  Did you read the link from McNets' comment?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that? Why don't you just use a set returning function? What do you think you need a ref cursor?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am learning ref cursor stuff. What I need is a theoretical explanation on why it doesn't work. :)

Comment: The answer is in the manual (because PL/pgSQL is something different than SQL) and the link from McNets' comment

Comment: Right.. got it. That's how it is designed and it makes sense. Thanks for the help! If McNets or a_horse_with_no_name could reply to the question I could mark it as the answer.